# gaussian projection versus gaussian noise

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am facing difficulties with the following layer in keras:

```
gaussian_projection = 64
gaussian_scale = 20

initializer = tf.keras.initializers.TruncatedNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=gauss_scale)

proj_kernel = tf.keras.layers.Dense(gaussian_projection, use_bias=False, trainable=False,
                                                    kernel_initializer=initializer)
```

What does above layers intends to do? Is it a layer to add gaussian noise or something different?

I hope someone knows about it.

#####################  Another 2nd version of the layer  ##########

```
input_dim = 3

new_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(input_dim, use_bias=False, trainable=False,
                                                        kernel_initializer='identity')

tf.keras.layers.GaussianNoise(stddev=gaussian_scale)
```

Does both version of layers (1st and 2nd) intends to do the same thing, i.e., adding gaussian noise?

Answer (score 1):

I think the above 2 are different as follows:

- The first block of codes basically create a `Dense` layer, in which the `gaussian_projection` variable is the number of units and the `initializer` is a way to initialize the layer. This initialization is normally done to improve the convergence of the layer and network; but overall, the first block of codes is a typical `Dense` layer. I think there is no noise added in this first block of code.
- On the other hand, the second block of codes create a `GaussianNoise` layer after the Dense layer, which is normally done to regularize the network and reduce overfitting. And based on the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GaussianNoise), this `GaussianNoise` layer is only active during training.

Comment: Okay, let's focus only on the first block of codes. Actually, I adopted this codes from it, https://github.com/titu1994/tf_fourier_features/blob/master/tf_fourier_features/fourier_features.py     Could you explain to me, what is the purpose of using `gaussian_projection` layer ?  If it is not gaussian noise then its just a dense layer. But, there is also gaussian scale used in the `initializer`. So, what this layer intends to do by `initializer` with `gaussian scale` ?

Comment: It's pretty clear in your first block of codes that gaussian_projection is a variable, not a layer, so I don't really understand what you are referring to?

Comment: I mean the dense layer that is using gaussian_projection and gaussian_scale as the variables

Comment: I checked the link you provided above and also the original paper; however I am sorry that I am not familiar with the topic discussed in the paper. Nevertheless, I saw in page 3 of the original paper in arvix that  "Let f be a fully-connected deep network
with weights θ initialized from a Gaussian distribution ...  the function f(x; θ) converges over the course of training to the kernel regression solution using the neural tangent kernel (NTK)"

Comment: and after checking the repo link you provided I think that the authors use Gaussian distribution initialization for the Dense weights (first version) to better approximate a kernel regression solution for their later Fourier transformation steps (e.g. sin/cos). This will be different from the 2nd version type, where you simply use a Dense layer with 'identity' initialization and not trying to approximate a kernel regression. Again, this is just my thinking, I'm sorry I cannot help you much more than this since I don't know the topic well.